# how many times will this loop execute

Tags: java, nested-loops

I was just wondering how many times a nested loop like this would run

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < total; j++) {
        for(int k = j; k < total; k++) {
            sum++;    
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

I can easily see the output of sum, but I would like to be able to mathematically calculate the total of `sum` with any number for `total`.

Comment: value of total..???

Comment: I guess you want to (mathematically) calculate `sum` without the loops

Comment: it is an arbitrary number

Comment: U are correct @user7

Comment: Then update the question addding this information.

Comment: Your code has _o(N^3)_ [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). :P

Comment: Question has been udpated

Comment: To be honest I think this question should be moved to [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/).

Comment: Hint: the sum of `1 + ... + n` is `(n + 1) * n / 2`

Comment: @KaiserKatze, I don't think it would be N^3 looking at the initial values of `j` & `k`.

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran I was think it would be something along the lines of o(nlog(n))

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran In my mind, _o_ mark is only a mark representing an approximate evaluation of potential behaviour of a piece of specified code. It's not precise. But this discussion is off-topic here. :)

Comment: Anyway, checkout [Arithmetic Progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)

Comment: @KaiserKatze, just clearing doubts :)

Comment: @J.Doe, yup it almost looks like O(nlog(n)) on best case I guess.

Comment: Okay, I got my own mathematica answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52143547/4927212

Comment: Hmmm, so far most answers verify that your code has _o(N^3)_ time complexity.

Comment: Appears so. It looked like nlog(n) to me

Comment: @J.Doe So are you going to accept my answer? PLZ.  xP

Comment: dont know how to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

The loop will be executed for `((total ^ 3) - total) / 6` times and hence that will be the value of `sum` at the end of the loop.

---

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < total; i++) { 
    for(int j = i + 1; j < total; j++) {
        for(int k = j; k < total; k++) {
            sum++;    
        }
    }
}
```

It is easy to see that the outer loop runs for a `total` times. The second loop is the trickier one

Let's try to work this out

`i = 0`, `j` runs from `1..total - 1`

`i = 1`, `j` runs from `2..total - 1`

`i = 2`, `j` runs from `3..total - 1`

...
`i = total - 2`, `j` runs from `total - 1 ..total - 1` (will only run once)

`i = total - 1`, inner loop does not execute as the loop termination condition is true.

The third loop is dependent on the second inner loop - `k` runs from `j..total - 1`

Let us take total as 6

`j` runs from `1..5` -> `k` runs for 5 times (`j = 1`) + 4 times(`j = 2`) + 3 times(`j = 3`)+ 2 times(`j = 4`) + 1 time(`j = 4`)

(Showing a minified version for others)

```
2..5 -> 4+3+2+1
3..5 3+2+1
4..5 2+1
5..5 1
```

Which is

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5+
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 
1 + 2 + 3 +
1 + 2 +
1
```

Generally,

```
1 + 2 + 3 + .. n +
1 + 2 + 3 +..n - 1+
1 + 2 + 3 +..n - 2+
1 + 2 + 3 +
1 + 2 +
1
```

This boils down to the sum 
`n * (n - 1)) / 2`

For **all values** of `n` ranging from `1 to total`

This can be verified with the below

```
int res = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
    res += (i * (i - 1))/2;
}
```

`res` will be equal to your `sum`.

Mathematically, the above is

```
((total ^ 3) - total) / 6
```

Derivation:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**References:**

[Sums of the First n Natural Numbers](https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalNumbers.htm)

[Sum of the Squares of the First n Natural Numbers](https://trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalSquares.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It needs only a little bit knowledge of programming.Actually logic that is running behind is only computational kind of thing.
let's say:

```
total=10,sum=0
```

**- when i is 0:**

That time j is initialised with 1(i+1) and k as well. So k will lead us to execute the loop 9 times and and as j is incremented ,it will lead us to execute sum statement 8 times and 7 times and further 6 times till 1 time. (9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1=45 times.)

**- when i is 1:**

That time j is initialised with 2 and k as well.So sum statement is going to execute 8 times and then 7 times and then 6 times till 1.
(8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1=36 times).

**- when i is 2:**

Same thing happens repeatedly but starting with difference number ,so this time (7+6+5+4+3+2+1=28)

- So this sequence continues until there is significance of occuring the condition with trueness.
  This happens till i is 9.

So the final answer is 1+3+6+10+15+21+28+36+45=165.

Answer (score 1):

The first iteration of the middle loop adds

```
total-1 + total-2 + ... + 1
```

to the sum.

The second iteration of the middle loop adds

```
total-2 + total - 3 + ... + 1
```

to the sum

The last iteration of the middle loop adds

```
1
```

to the sum.

If you sum all of these terms, you get

```
(total - 1) * 1 + (total - 2) * 2 + (total - 3) * 3 + ... + 2 * (total - 2) + 1 * (total - 1)
```

It's been a while since I studied math, so I don't remember if there's a simpler formula for this expression.

For example, if total is 10, you get:

```
9 * 1 + 8 * 2 + 7 * 3 + 6 * 4 + 5 * 5 + 4 * 6 + 3 * 7 + 2 * 8 + 1 * 9 =
9 + 16 + 21 + 24 + 25 + 24 + 21 + 16 + 9 = 
165
```

Answer (score 0):

outermost loop  runs 'total' number of times.

for each outer loop , middle loop runs 'total-i' times.

i.e  total * total+total * (total-1)+total * (total-2)....total * 1

= total*(total+total-1+total-2...1)

= total*(1+2+3....total)

= total*(sum of first 'total' natural numbers)

= total*(total*(total+1)/2)

now the innermost loop also runs 'total-j' times for each middle loop

i.e 
      total*(total*(total+1)/2)*(total+(total-1)+(total-2)....+1)

= total*(total*(total+1)/2)*(1+2+3....+total)

= total*(total*(total+1)/2)* (sum of first 'total' natural numbers)

= total*(total*(total+1)/2) * (total*(total+1)/2)..
So finally you will get something close  to

> total * (total*(total+1)/2) * (total*(total+1)/2).

Sorry there's a correction as @andreas mentioned innermost and middle loops run only till total-i-1 times 
in which case it will be the sum of first (total-1) no.s which should be (total-1)*total/2 so the final output should be

> total * (total*(total-1)/2) * (total*(total-1)/2) .

Comment: No, for each outer loop , middle loop runs 'total-i-1' times.

Comment: hmmm in which case it will be the sum of first (total-1) no.s which should be (total-1)*total/2 so the final output should be total * (total*(total-1)/2) * (total*(total-1)/2)

Answer (score 0):

The equation is like below
and the k is equal to total :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As we know, the sum of an arithmetic progression is:

### [image]

The inner-most loop will loop for

[image]

times, which is a function to `j`.

You sum it up and get a function to `i`, aka:

[image]

You sum it up again and get a function to `total`, aka:

[image]

---

For [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica) users, the result is:

```
f[x_]:=Sum[Sum[x-j,{j,i+1,x-1}],{i,0,x-1}]
```

From [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%5Bx_%5D:%3DSum%5BSum%5Bx-j,%7Bj,i%2B1,x-1%7D%5D,%7Bi,0,x-1%7D%5D), we can see it more clearly, and the ***FINAL*** result is:

[image]

where `x` is `total`.

Answer (score 0):

If we run this loop 100 times and generate a data set, then graph it, we get this: [image]

Now, this graph is clearly a cubic. So we can do a solve using the cubic equation of ax^3+bx^2+cx+d.

Using 4 points, the values of them all are:

[image]

So the full equation is

```
y=x^3/6-x/6
y=x(x^2/6-1/6)
y=(x/6)(x^2-1)
```

Interactive Graph:

```html
<iframe src="https://www.desmos.com/calculator/61whd83djd?embed" width="500px" height="500px" style="border: 1px solid #ccc" frameborder=0></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

That function will loop `(total/6)*(total*total - 1)` times
The snippet bellow just verifies that

```js
var total = 100
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    for(var j = i + 1; j < total; j++) {
        for(var k = j; k < total; k++) {
            sum++;    
        }
    }
}

function calc(n) {
  return n*(n-1)*(n+1)/6
}

console.log("sum: "+sum)
console.log("calc: "+calc(total))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop like this:

```
for (i = a; i < b; i ++) {
    ....
}
```

runs `b-a` iterations (`i` takes the values: `a`, `a+1`, `a+2`... `b-2`, `b-1`) if `a < b` and `0` iterations otherwise. We will assume below that `a < b` always.

Its number of iterations can be compute using the simple maths formula:

[image: sum(i=a,b-1) 1]

#### Applying the formula to your code

We start with the innermost loop:

```
for(int k = j; k < t; k++) {
    sum++;    
}
```

Its number of iterations is:

[image: sum(k=j,t-1) 1]

Using the formula above, the value of `U` is `(t-1)-j+1` which means:

```
U = t - j
```

#### Adding the middle loop

Adding the middle loop, the number of iterations becomes:

[image: sum(j=i+1,t) sum(k=j,t-1) 1]

The terms of the second sum are `t-(i+1)`, `t-(i+2)`, ... `t-(t-2)`, `t-(t-1)`.
By solving the parentheses and putting them in the reverse order they can be written as:
`1`, `2`, ... `t-i-2`, `t-i-1`.

Let `p = t - j`. The second sum now becomes:

[image: sum(p=1,t-i-1) p]

It is the [sum of the first `t-i-1` natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) and its value is:

[image: sum(p=1,t-i-1) p=(t-i-1)*(t-i)/2]

#### Adding the outer loop

Adding the outer loop the sum becomes:

[image: sum(i=0,t-1) sum(j=i+1,t) sum(k=j,t-1) 1=sum(i=0,t-1)((t-i-1)*(t-i)/2)=1/2*sum(i=0,t-1)(((t-i)-1)*(t-i))]

On the last sum, the expression `(t - i)` starts with `t` (when `i = 0`), continues with `t-1` (when `i = 1`) and it keeps decreasing until it reaches `1` (when `i = t - 1`). By replacing `q = t - i`, the last sum becomes:

[image: 1/2*sum(q=1,t)((q-1)*q)]

The last expression subtracts [the sum of the first `n` natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) from [the sum of the first `n` square numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number). Its value is:

[image: S=1/2*(sum(q=1,t)q^2-sum(q=1,t)q)=1/2*((t*(t+1)*(2t+1))/6-(t*(t+1))/2)]

Now it's easy to simplify the expression:

[image: S=1/2*1/6*(t*(t+1))*(2t+1-3)=1/6*(t*(t+1)*(t-1))=(t^3-t)/6]

#### The final answer

The number of iterations of the posted code is:

[image: (t^3-t)/6]